# There's a Red Dashed Box With Text... How Do I Position The Current Date (In Javascript?) In That Box?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's The Problem:

The date is on the top left--and non-bolded, non-red. My outcome is for it to bold, red, and in the dashed-red bordered box.

I've set the getElementById attribute to equal "datetext", which is the id of a "p" tag in the red paragraph text.

What do I need to do to get everything positioned according to this outcome?

```
<p class="warning">

      <span>            
      WARNING: Due to recently being featured on T.V. we cannot guarantee supply.<br/>
        As of <p id="datetext"></p> we currently have product IN STOCK and ship within 24 hours.
      </span>
```

http://puregarcinaextract.net/

P.S. I've put a couple hours into this--let me know if you need any specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some code like this:

```
document.getElementById('datetext').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: Sorry... Doesn't work... I'm thinking of reasons why my code isn't working with your suggestion. :/

Comment: When I go to the page and run the code in the JS console it does the change fine. I suspect your JS is being run out of order or the style of the page is hiding the text. Which really isn't what this question was about...

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me ha. I used to be a total code junkie--but it's definitely been a while. Do you know what the right next step is - in order to get the date in that dashed-bordered box? (Update: My question wasn't clear--sorry about that!)

Comment: Well, I'd use something other than a <p> element for datetext as it's not a paragraph and the spacing around a <p> messes up the layout. I'm not sure if you mean't to put it outside of <p id="warning"> but it should probably be inside of there. I tried a <span> element for it but part of your style.css is adding margins around spans inside warning, so I'd recommend you fix that CSS by making it more specific, so as to let you use a span element without it adding the margin.

Comment: Sorry but this question has gotten pretty off-topic. I hope you think I've helped enough to accept my answer and ask future concise questions about any issues that might arise.

Comment: You're right - Gonna see what I can do with the CSS now... Thanks a lot for your help, stealth! Get back to you soon.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the site. Hope I'm not nagging, but if you're satisfied with this thread please click the checkmark next to my answer, or refer to this answer if you're not sure what I mean or why I'd bother asking: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work